# Pasting merged cells using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy a row of data from an excel sheet and transfer that to another sheet, but the range of row data has a two column merged cell in it and I'm having trouble pasting without any errors.

Any tips would be very helpful,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For copy a merged cells, you need mention range.
Example : A9 and B9 were merged, you need use `Range("A9:B9").Copy` to copy the merged cell

Comment: Thanks for the reply Keong, Here's a copy of my code, I don't know how to change it to make it work for merged cells.. `Sheet1.Range(Cells(a, 4), Cells(a, 10)).Copy
        Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial` Sheet1 and Sheet2 are declared as variables, they have different values and not declared as "Sheet1" per se, i just changed it up a lil differently.

Comment: I mean I just changed the values when i posted it here

Comment: Just remove `PasteSpecial` and it worked. Here is what I tried : `Sheet1.Range(Cells(9, 4), Cells(9, 10)).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`

Comment: It's not working for me. I still get the "We can't do that to a merged cell." I'm pasting it on a range of cells that also has a merged cells

Comment: Mind edit your question by pasting your source code?